# Null propagation operator and foreach

Tags: c#, null, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

Reading a lot about the [Null propagation operator `?.`](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883), I found no answer whether it is helpful in the following scenario.

Code that throws:

```
int[] values = null;

foreach ( var i in values ) // Throws since values is null.
{
    // ...
}
```

To make this working, I have to add a `null` check before access to the `values` variable.

Most likely the above code is out of scope of the design considerations for the Null propagation operator. Still, to be sure, I have to ask.

**My question:**

Is the Null propagation operator helpful when trying to access `null` collections in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Not an answer but you could write `foreach ( var i in values ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())` to avoid nesting.

Comment: Or use ArrayList or List <T> instead :)

Comment: @Boctulus Those are nullable reference types, too, you know?!?

Comment: @UweKeim : If he uses ArrayList or List <T> no NullReferenceException will throw, you know ?

Comment: @Boctulus [Sure?](http://ideone.com/ariXga)

Comment: Also see this Roslyn issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6563

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not. It's designed to allow access members of an object in a secure way. In this case you have to check whether the array is *null*.

Answer (score 12):

I've found another, working way:

When using Jon Skeet's (et al) fantastic [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq) extensions, there is a [`ForEach` extension method](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ForEach/) which I can use in my initial example like:

```
int[] values = null;

values?.ForEach(i=> /*...*/); // Does not throw, even values is null.
```

Comment: There is a `ForEach` extension in `System.Collections.Generic`. There is no need to use MoreLinq anymore. And it also works with null propagation without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

How would you porpose to use it?

The code you provided:

```
int[] values = null;

foreach (var i in values)
{
    // ...
}
```

enxpands into something:

```
int[] values = null;

var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var i = enumerator.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
finally
{
    var disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I guess you could write something like this:

```
int[] values = null;

foreach (var i in values?.)
{
    // ...
}
```

The compiler would have to expand it to something like this:

```
int[] values = null;

var enumerator = values?.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator?.MoveNext() ?? false)
    {
        var i = enumerator.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
finally
{
    var disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And have in mind that:

```
a = b?.M();
```

expands into:

```
a = b == null ? null : b.M();
```

If you want to not explicitly write the `if` statement, you can always rely on the good old [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
int[] values = null;

foreach (var i in values ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `List<T>` you can use `list?.ForEach(i => ...);` and for other enumerables you can make your own ForEach extension like this:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {

    if (source == null) { return; }

    foreach (T item in source) {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

You call it like this: `myPossiblyNullEnumerable.ForEach(i => ...);`

If you want your ForEach extension to throw when called for null enumerables, you can just leave the null check away, and call it with the same elvis syntax as the List's version: `myPossiblyNullEnumerable?.ForEach(i => ...);`